# How to collect historical data using smartctl?

Tags: hard-drive, database, datacenter, smart, smartctl

I'm trying to do some analysis on the SMART stats of disk drives. Unfortunately, I'm not collecting/storing smart stats data daily for the analysis. I will be writing some procedure to collect it from now.

I was thinking, that disk drives has its own embedded predictive/recovery models. So, in order for these embedded predictive models to work, smartctl must be having its own database where it may store some "historical data"?

Am I thinking right? Is it possible to fetch some historical data using smartctl or any other way?